# Azure IOT Hub to on premise database server

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have data in Azure IOT hub.

I know we can transfer this data to any cloud based storage like

for storing IoT data in Azure cloud such as:

Azure Blob storage if you need to store a large amount of cold data with a low-prices. Stored IoT data can be on-demand loaded into some SQL Database or SQL DW to run analytic using standard queries or analyzed using some Azure Machine Learning service.
Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL DW if you can parse incoming data and store it in the relational format.
Azure SQL Database if you need to store semi-structured data formatted as JSON and you need to correlate IoT information with some existing relational data.
Azure SQL Database or Azure Cosmos DB if you need to store semi-structured data formatted as JSON.

But can we get the Azure IOT data to on premises local storage database server.

Comment: The answer is yes, but there are so many ways to do it that I couldn't begin to answer. In the end, you would need a piece of software to listen to the device telemetry and store that in your database.

Comment: If you are looking for a framework functionality, please provide your feedback here and upvote for this feature: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/35018644-azure-iot-hub-to-local-on-premise-database-sql-or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data by having a service that connect to Events endpoint and insert the data in your local database. Your service will be on-premises or have access to your on-premises database.